# When to call add_filter

Tags: plugins, filters, wpdb

I am using wp_video_shortcode_override filter in one of my plugins. I would like to make this as on option top user so its not active by default. I have set up following scenario. I need to call wpdb to get some options from my plugin. Is this the good achitecture?

```
add_action('init', 'foo_init_setup');

function foo_init_setup() {

    global $wpdb;
    $settings_table = $wpdb->prefix . "foo_settings";
    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT options FROM {$settings_table} WHERE id = '0'", ARRAY_A);
    $settings = unserialize($result['options']);
    $overide_video = (bool)($settings["overide_video"]);

    if($overide_video)add_filter('wp_video_shortcode_override', 'foo_video_shortcode_override', 10, 2 );

}

function foo_video_shortcode_override( $html, $attr ) {

    //something here

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this like that.

You can call `foo_init_setup` on `init` or on `wp` hook and it will work just fine.

I would call it as late as possible, I guess. This way you won't affect loading time for requests that don't end with page rendering (for example when `template_redirect` is used for redirecting).

PS. There is much bigger problem with your code, though. You create custom table and store only one row with serialized array containing options for your plugin.

It would be much nicer, if you used [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).

Comment: Which hook could I use to call it later, but to assure it will still work when needed?